# Adding multiple records from one unbound form vba access

Tags: forms, vba, ms-access

I have one unbound form where I can enter values for `Order 1`, `Order 2`, `Order 3`. Using a button called "SAVE_LOAD" I would like to enter it to a table "LOAD DATA ENTRY" where `Order 1` will create one record row, `Order 2` a second row and so on. So far I used the following `on_click` event but it only adds one row for `Order 1`. How do you add the rest of the orders as separate rows? Please help I am new to this.

```
Private Sub SAVE_LOAD_Click()
    InsSQL = "INSERT INTO [LOAD DATA ENTRY] ( [ORDER NO], [OPERATION NAME], [SH SPEC], [FINISHED ITEM NO], [FINISHED ITEM DESCRIPTION], [ORDER QTY], [VACUUM EQUIPMENT], [LOAD], [LOAD QTY], [LOAD RACKING], [NO OF BASKETS], [BASKET PLACEMENT], [LOT BASKET AND SAMPLES], [MAX WEIGHT], [ACTUAL WEIGHT], [LOAD DAILY ID]) " & _
             " Values ('" & Me.ORDER_NO_1 & "','" & Me.OPERATION_NAME_1 & "','" & Me.HT_SPEC_1 & "','" & Me.FINISHED_ITEM_NO_1 & "','" & Me.FINISHED_ITEM_DESCRIPTION_1 & "','" & Me.ORDER_QTY_1 & "','" & Me.VACUUM_EQUIPMENT_1 & "','" & Me.LOAD_NUMBER_ID & "','" & Me.LOAD_QTY_1 & "','" & Me.LOAD_RACKING_1 & "','" & Me.NO_OF_BASKETS_1 & "','" & Me.BASKET_LOCATION_1 & "','" & Me.LOT_BASKET___SAMPLES_1 & "','" & Me.MAX_WEIGHT_1 & "','" & Me.ACTUAL_WEIGHT_1 & "','" & Me.LOAD_DAILY_ID & "')"
```

[image: Unbound Form]

Comment: Simplest (but least-maintainable) approach would be to just repeat that line two more times.

Comment: Why not bound this orders form to a table? Access has the continuous form type for multiple row data entry.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to iterate it:

```
Dim i as Integer

    for i = 1 to 3
        InsSQL = "INSERT INTO [LOAD DATA ENTRY] ( [ORDER NO], [OPERATION NAME], [SH SPEC], [FINISHED ITEM NO], [FINISHED ITEM DESCRIPTION], [ORDER QTY], [VACUUM EQUIPMENT], [LOAD], [LOAD QTY], [LOAD RACKING], [NO OF BASKETS], [BASKET PLACEMENT], [LOT BASKET AND SAMPLES], [MAX WEIGHT], [ACTUAL WEIGHT], [LOAD DAILY ID]) " & _
                 " Values ('" & Me.ORDER_NO_"' & i,'" & Me.OPERATION_NAME_"' & i,'" & Me.HT_SPEC_"' & i,'" & Me.FINISHED_ITEM_NO_"' & i,'" & Me.FINISHED_ITEM_DESCRIPTION_"' & i,'" & Me.ORDER_QTY_"' & i,'" & Me.VACUUM_EQUIPMENT_"' & i,'" & Me.LOAD_NUMBER_ID & "','" & Me.LOAD_QTY_"' & i,'" & Me.LOAD_RACKING"' & i,'" & Me.NO_OF_BASKETS_"' & i,'" & Me.BASKET_LOCATION_"' & i,'" & Me.LOT_BASKET___SAMPLES_"' & i,'" & Me.MAX_WEIGHT_"' & i,'" & Me.ACTUAL_WEIGHT_"' & i,'" & Me.LOAD_DAILY_ID & "')"

    next i
```